# NOT NULL constraint failed: product_product.author_id

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

When I am going to post objects in the postman I am getting this error

> NOT NULL constraint failed: product_product.author_id

I included Basic Auth in the Authorization section anyway it gives me error.

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
brand = models.CharField(max_length=200)
rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
description = models.TextField()
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
category = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), slug_field='name')
author = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.username')
class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ['id', 'url', 'category', 'name', 'brand', 'rating', 'description', 'price']
```

Why Not Null constraint happens? how can I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to set ```ForeignKey``` even though you don't add it in the seralizer. Or you need to add ```blank=True, null=True``` in the models.py

Comment: @cagrias thanks for the answer yes it is right when I add null=True it works but in the admin page I do not know which user added instead i shows None. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: you have to specify an author when creating a product. add author field available in create product screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add models.create_all() in Models.py to create the database

Answer (score 0):

The error happens simply because your create request is not providing a value for
`author` attribute of a product.

```
# models.py

class Product(models.Model):
    ....
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

so in order to resolve this issue totally depends on your business logic,

- **Is it important for a product to have an Author?**

  - **[NO]** ==> then just make the foreign key `null=True, blank=True`
  - **[YES]** ==> Then you need to modify your creation logic a lil bit.
- **Is the author of a product is the same one who created it?**

  - **[YES]**, then this can easily be done by overriding your serializer's create method

  ```
      ....
      # Inside you serializer
      def create(self, validated_data):
          validated_data['author'] = self.context['request'].user
          return super().create(validated_data)
  ```

  - **[NO]**, You have to make the serializer accept writes on `author` field.

> A small note, your `ProductSerializer` Meta class's fields attribute, doesn't include 'author', make sure it is added there too.